# How to Find R.M.S value

Tags: ac, homework, rms

how can I find the R.M.S value of this question?

[image]

Comment: We don't answer homework questions unless you show a good attempt to answer it yourself first and tell us exactly where you got stuck. So how far have you got?

Comment: I just couldn't find the f(t) for that graph :((

Comment: Treat it as two separate sections: A straight line function for half of the time and zero for the other half.

Comment: The root of the mean of the square. So first, you square the data series or function. Then you calculate the mean of that (this is a matter of evaluating an integral over exactly one period of the waveform.. see mean value theorem) then you take the square root of the mean. This is the mathematical definition of RMS and always works. Sometimes you can use shortcuts for particular waveforms such as sine waves or square waves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Comment: @mkeith, that should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the mean of the square. So first, you square the data series or function. Then you calculate the mean of that (this is a matter of evaluating an integral over exactly one period of the waveform.. see mean value theorem) then you take the square root of the mean. This is the mathematical definition of RMS and always works. Sometimes you can use shortcuts for particular waveforms such as sine waves or square waves.

Answer (score -1):

check this link. i think you can find your answer there .

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square

First you must write the function that generate this shape for you. then put that function in the formula that is exist in the link mentioned above.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would image the person who did wouldn't want you to answer the question like this. It's not very effective for an answer to be something like, "Here's the website for the answer, go find what you need."

Comment: its because of i want him to know where is the source of that formula! i also could just screenshot the formula just like @laptop2d do!!!

Comment: @Amin to generate good answers, link only answers are discouraged here because links change, then the answer is worthless.

Comment: @laptop2d i think you are who downvoted me! Your answer exactly is as same as i mentioned plus one screenshot! ;)

Comment: I might be but there is no way to tell for sure, if you edit your answer ( fix capitalization and make the answer not link only) I might be inclined to upvote, as it stands this answer should be removed.

Comment: @laptop2d Its does not matter if you down ward me or to be inclined! to upvote. i just want to help him to find his answer and i think i could and that is enough for me.